# how to get the number of products inside cart in shopify?

Tags: e-commerce, shopify

I already know how to get the number of items, so let's say I have 3 shirts A and 2 pants B in my cart, I would like to get 2 instead of 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[See here.](http://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/ecommerce-design/t/query-number-of-different-products-in-cart-140624)

Use `cart.items.size` to get the number of unique products in your cart.